# Esconder e abrir div em determinadas condições

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com problemas em abrir e fechar uma barra de pesquisa determinada.

Preciso abrir uma `div` enquanto focus estiver no campo e tirar enquanto não tiver, porém quando clicar na `div` que está em aberto não poderá ser removido o focus do campo e nem fechado.

Tentei colocar o evento no `body`, em uma `div` superior porém não funcionou ele continua fechando.

Este é o código que tenho utilizado:

```
$("input[name='search-input']").blur( function() {
     $(".divCompleteSearch").addClass('hiddendiv');
});

$("input[name='search-input']").focus( function() {
    $(".divCompleteSearch").removeClass('hiddendiv');
});

$(".button-search").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("input[name='search-input']").focus();
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="row align-content-center">
    <div class="col search-bar">
        <div class="col m1 icon-search-bar">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"
                 style="height: 22px; width: 22px; display: block; fill: currentcolor;">
                <path
                    d="m2.5 7c0-2.5 2-4.5 4.5-4.5s4.5 2 4.5 4.5-2 4.5-4.5 4.5-4.5-2-4.5-4.5m13.1 6.9-2.8-2.9c.7-1.1 1.2-2.5 1.2-4 0-3.9-3.1-7-7-7s-7 3.1-7 7 3.1 7 7 7c1.5 0 2.9-.5 4-1.2l2.9 2.8c.2.3.5.4.9.4.3 0 .6-.1.8-.4.5-.5.5-1.2 0-1.7"></path>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="col m11 input-search-bar">
            <input type="text" name="search-input" placeholder="Experimente Colegio São Fransisco">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row align-content-center divCompleteSearch hiddendiv">
    <div class="col complete-search">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col m3 button-search active">
                Escolas
            </div>
            <div class="col m3 button-search">
                Bairro
            </div>
            <div class="col m3 button-search">
                Telefone
            </div>
            <div class="col m3 button-search">
                Apelido
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesta primeira imagem é a `div` fechada, quando ha o focus no `input search` ele deve abrir a segunda imagem, a `div` deve ficar aberta até que ele clica em qualquer lugar que não seja dentro da `div` aberta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o evento `mouseenter` dentro da `div` para verificar enquanto o mouse estiver na div e assim adicionar uma classe para controle, por exemplo `divativa`, no evento `mouseleave` ou seja, quando o mouse não estiver mais focado na div, ele irá remover a classe de controle.

No seu evento de `blur`, apenas verifiquei se a `div` está ou não com a classe de controle, se não estiver, ele pode adicionar a classe para esconde-la.

```js
$('.divCompleteSearch').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $(this).addClass('divativa');
})

$('.divCompleteSearch').on('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('divativa');
})

$("input[name='search-input']").blur( function() {     
     if(!$('.divCompleteSearch').hasClass('divativa')) {
        $(".divCompleteSearch").addClass('hiddendiv');
     }     
});


$("input[name='search-input']").focus( function() {
    $(".divCompleteSearch").removeClass('hiddendiv');
});

$(".button-search").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("input[name='search-input']").focus();
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.hiddendiv {
  display: none;
}
.divCompleteSearch {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.outradiv {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row align-content-center">
    <div class="col search-bar">
        <div class="col m1 icon-search-bar">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"
                 style="height: 22px; width: 22px; display: block; fill: currentcolor;">
                <path
                    d="m2.5 7c0-2.5 2-4.5 4.5-4.5s4.5 2 4.5 4.5-2 4.5-4.5 4.5-4.5-2-4.5-4.5m13.1 6.9-2.8-2.9c.7-1.1 1.2-2.5 1.2-4 0-3.9-3.1-7-7-7s-7 3.1-7 7 3.1 7 7 7c1.5 0 2.9-.5 4-1.2l2.9 2.8c.2.3.5.4.9.4.3 0 .6-.1.8-.4.5-.5.5-1.2 0-1.7"></path>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="col m11 input-search-bar">
            <input type="text" name="search-input" placeholder="Experimente Colegio São Fransisco">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row align-content-center divCompleteSearch hiddendiv">
    <div class="col complete-search">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col m3 button-search active">
                Escolas
            </div>
            <div class="col m3 button-search">
                Bairro
            </div>
            <div class="col m3 button-search">
                Telefone
            </div>
            <div class="col m3 button-search">
                Apelido
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <br><br>
<div class="outradiv">
  OUTRA DIV, clique para fechar a de cima
</div>
```

Inseri uma borda nas `divs` para ficar mais fácil de visualizar e testar.